# Colon in date format between seconds and milliseconds. How to parse in R?

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, milliseconds, strptime

How can I parse this date format? Should I change this colon to dot or maybe someone know better solution?

```
> x <- "2012.01.15 09:00:02:002"
> strptime(x, "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S:%OS") 
[1] "2012-01-15 09:00:02"
> strptime(x, "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2012-01-15 09:00:02"
> x <- "2012.01.15 09:00:02.002"
> strptime(x, "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2012-01-15 09:00:02.001"
```

Comment: Both answers are correct +1! but personally I prefere gsubfn :D

Comment: Do you actually know that the number past last colon is fractional seconds?  It could be something else, like frames.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a subtle distinction here that may be throwing you off. 
As `?strptime` notes:

> for 'strptime' '%OS' will input seconds including fractional seconds.

To emphasize that a bit, `%OS` represents the seconds **including** fractional seconds --- not just the fractional **part** of the seconds: if the seconds value is 44.234, `%OS` or `%OS3` represents *44.234*,  not *.234*

So the solution is indeed to substitute a `.` for that final `:`.

Here's one way you might do that:

```
x <- "2012.01.15 09:00:02:002"
strptime(gsub(":", ".", x), "%Y.%m.%d %H.%M.%OS")
```

Comment: +1. I think the OP already knew all that -- you'll note that (s)he uses that fact in the last thing (s)he tried -- but it's likely to be useful to other people who might be coming across this question.

Comment: @ruakh -- Good point, and I suspect you're right. I like that the quote from `?strptime` makes the point extra unambiguous.

Comment: Yes indeed i've converted colon to dots. Thx for quick reply :)

Answer (score 2):

Would

```
strptime(gsub(":", ".", x), "%Y.%m.%d %H.%M.%OS3")
```

be cheating?

Comment: `sub` will only replace the first instance of  a `:` with a `.` rather than each instance.  you'll need `gsub` for that as per @JoshO'Brien's answer

Comment: @Justin: I think I'd actually already fixed that by the time you commented, but thank you. :-)