# DateTime with comma separated millisecond format in R

Tags: r, datetime

Hello I need to cast dateTimes character like `"20/2/06 11:16:16,683"` and having difficulties to do it.
I have tried the classic (NO COMMA FOR MILLI):

```
R) strptime("20/2/06 11:16:16.683", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2006-02-20 11:16:16.682"
```

This fails for the format I have:

```
R) strptime("20/2/06 11:16:16,683", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2006-02-20 11:16:16"
```

This too:

```
R) strptime("20/2/06 11:16:16,683", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M,%OS")
[1] NA
```

Is there a way to do this directly or should I use a `gsub` like function to replace the `,` with a `.` before using strptime.

Comment: This is extremely similar to [Colon in date format between seconds and milliseconds. How to parse in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13613655/271616).

Comment: Indeed... we concluded the same thing so all good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do the conversion manually.

Here my suggestion without using gsub, but with scan

```
 ll <- scan(text = "20/2/06 11:16:16,683",sep=',',what="character")
 as.POSIXct(ll[1],format=("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%OS"))+ as.numeric(ll[2])/1000

 [1] "2006-02-20 11:16:16.683 CET"
```

Comment: Ok I think it cannot be done in one go...
I did `myFun <- function(from){strptime(gsub(pattern=",",replacement=".",from), format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS")}`